# How to merge rows based on the same value in R?

Tags: r

My data is organized as eg:

```
x  country 
1  FR
1  FR
1  NO
2  UK
3  ES
3  ES
4  NO
```

So I have repetitions of the same x and country for several rows, and sometimes while x is the same the country changes

How can I merge rows if the country and x are repeatedly the same for several rows, while taking into account that in some cases the country is different for the same x?

Comment: `duplicated()`?

Comment: You could try with `merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, by = "x")`, but its hard to recommend without seeing more of your data.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your goal correctly, maybe you need to use `unique`

```
> unique(df)
  x country
1 1      FR
3 1      NO
4 2      UK
5 3      ES
7 4      NO
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), country = c("FR", 
"FR", "NO", "UK", "ES", "ES", "NO")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-7L))
```